# I wish to add custom section in product detail page in magento 2

Tags: ajax, magento2.2.6, product-page, custom-button

How to add custom button in product page,while clicking that button it needs to show custom form in a popup ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so first create a `.phtml` file under `app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/send_request.phtml`

then, add this `.phtml` file reference in `catalog.xml` in `/app/design/frontend/[namespace]/[theme]/layout/catalog.xml`

```
<block type="core/template" name="customer_request" template="catalog/product/send_request.phtml"/>
```

below the :
`<label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>`

section but you should find to right section where to place ( you will find after a few try )

Finally, the form contain that you implemented in `send_request.phtml` will available under product view page.

Now create a `href` link and a form in `send_request.phtml`. After this add js to hide / show.